# Notepad++ displaying java extremely pixelized

Tags: notepad++

Here is a picture of what is happening.  This problem only seems to occur with java.

When I switch languages its fine.  Is there any way to fix this?

I tried re-installing notepad++, and looking at the global style settings.  Neither of those worked.

[image: Java acting up picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the `Style Configurator` (menu entry `Settings`) and check the following setting:

[image: Notepad Style Configurator]

If you also have a Typeface selected there (selector `Font name`), like in my example, then try to deselect it by selecting the first and *empty* entry.